# isFinite returns true when variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm using isFinite to determine if a key from an array is correct,

```
for (x in selectList) {
        if (isFinite(x)) {
             $('#' + selectList[x])[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
}
```

I thought this was working correctly but now in Firefox isFinite is returning TRUE when x is  undefined. This doesn't seem right to me. Is this a bug?

Comment: `if(isFinite(x) && x!=undefined)`? isFinite only returns false on `infinite+`, `infinite-`, and `NaN`. Undefined and null could be interpreted as 0.

Comment: What is a correct key? isFinite() only returns false on NaN or infinity. You should look for a better way to do what you want.

Comment: @devius It also returns false on things that aren't numbers...

Comment: @lonesomeday It returns true on null, and that's probably what's going on here. If the variable was undefined it would also return false.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thats what I said! x shows undefined in firebug. Not true, false or null which would explain somethings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NEVER use `for..in` for arrays. There are number of things that could go wrong. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164) for explanation.

Just use a plain vanilla for loop. You don't need to use `isFinite` or `isNaN` then.

Comment: Agreed, it's actually a shame one cant use plain vanilla loop for an object too

Comment: @JCOC611: When ordering is important, use arrays. When you need faster lookups by keys, use objects. If you need both, you need to implement your own data structure like SortedMap :)

Comment: Yeah, but for ex. if one was to prototype the **Object** object, any `for..in` loops would include the prototyping...

Answer (score 0):

```
var d;
alert(isFinite(d));
```

This returns false for me using the firebug console.
(d is undefined since nothing has been assigned to it).

should you not be doing:

```
for (x in selectList) {
        if (isFinite(selectList[x])) { //x will always be defined since you are iterating through property names not the values
             $('#' + selectList[x])[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: No, he should use a plain `for` loop. See: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#arrays

Comment: A for loop will only function with an array that has numerical indices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be a bug. See [ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf). `isFinite(x)` should return `false` if `toNumber(x)` returns `NaN` (page 105) and `toNumber(x)` returns `NaN` if `x` is undefined (page 43).

Answer (score 0):

If `selectList` is ordinary array, just have ordinary plain loop:

```
for (var x = 0; x < selectList.length; x++) {
    $('#' + selectList[x])[0].selectedIndex = 0;
}
```